# Is a permanent job a thing of the past?

Tags: hiring

Not sure if it is just my experience, but it looks like the (U.S.) marketplace is after people willing to take 6 or 12 months contract projects, and offers of permanent placement are dwindling, nowadays being mostly offered by consulting firms (ironically).

Is that your view and experience, and when does one know it is worth switching from a permanent (secure, sometimes boring, steady and lower pay) to a contract route (less secure, possibly exciting and with higher pay potential)?

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped... avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid.." ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace as explained in the [help]

Comment: What trade are you in, and why would asking such a general question with so many potential subjective answers be of benefit to you? I am voting to close for that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would never suggest to a perm worker to leave and go contract.  Yes, it's more money (in the short term anyway), but it's a different mindset.  You need to be sorted financially (in case the gig ends tomorrow), also need to be able to be dropped into a new job and be productive immediately (no settling in time when you charge by the hour/day).  You also need to stay up to date of tools/techniques yourself.  Having said that, if it's for you it can be a great life, lots of variety and interesting projects.

I wouldn't say that permanent is dying out, just that the idea of a job for life has gone, think of permanent in terms of a few years, as opposed to the (likely) months of contract.